# Setup project does not find any assembly files " VS2015"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dependencies, windows-installer

I am trying to make a setup project using VS2015.
After building the project successfully and install ".exe " on my pc, i found that there is not any image processing library working

Ex: could not load file or assembly "Aforge"
EX: the type initializer for 'emgu.cv.cvinvoke' threw an exception

update:
when i make rebuild solution, rebuild complete successfully but i found some WARNING like this:

" Unable to find dependency 'AFORGE' (Signature='C1DB6FF4EAA06AEB' 
  Version='2.2.5.0') of assembly 'AForge.Math.dll' "

update:
Do i need to add an arbitrary file to my setup project like this

```
"File"
    {
        "{1FB2D0AE-D3B9-43D4-B9DD-F88EC61E35DE}:_06335985DF0F4EF3A600861437AA6CDF"
        {
        "SourcePath" = "8:..\\Debug\\CppWin32.dll"
        "TargetName" = "8:CppWin32.dll"
        "Tag" = "8:"
        "Folder" = "8:_1E4113F2F81040508FD1CDA54F242F25"
        "Condition" = "8:"
        "Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
        "Vital" = "11:TRUE"
        "ReadOnly" = "11:FALSE"
        "Hidden" = "11:FALSE"
        "System" = "11:FALSE"
        "Permanent" = "11:FALSE"
        "SharedLegacy" = "11:FALSE"
        "PackageAs" = "3:1"
        "Register" = "3:1"
        "Exclude" = "11:FALSE"
        "IsDependency" = "11:FALSE"
        "IsolateTo" = "8:"
        }
    }
```

Any help !
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the installed program not working, or about other programs getting problems? And after installation, does the install folder contain all the necessary dlls?

Comment: installed program is working correctly ,but the core functions which executed based on dlls not working and generate exceptions

like this exception:
Could not load file or assembly 'AForge, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c1db6ff4eaa06aeb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'AForge, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c1db6ff4eaa06aeb'

Comment: yes,install folder contains all the necessary dlls

Comment: but not working also all the used and necessary dlls exist into install folder !!

Comment: maybe your assembly isn't signed properly, check license.licx

Comment: also, drop down list of dependencies and see if there is yellow triangles like this /!\

Comment: how can i do this in right way ! 
ensuring that assembly files are signed correctly ?